# How to correcly display data that is not English as a radio button title

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, utf-8, utf

I am having an issue where some title for radio button are showing blank due to non-english characters in the title.

Here is example of a string from the database that is showing blank.

> WATERTOWN/171 Watertown St/Rte 16/Newton**ÿ**

The last character in the string is **ÿ**, that is what is causing the problem in this case.

How can I correct this problem?

On the very top of my page I have this code

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I am not sure if the character **ÿ** is not a valid UTF-8 or not.

I tried using the method `utf8_encode()` on the data before storing it into the SQL Server database but that did not work.

That is the problem here and how to fix it?

Comment: Paste your code + show us your DB structure

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc626307.aspx

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a little bit relaxed on everything, also on encoding. There is no real "encoding" you probaly know from other languages.

Actually it treats the string byte by byte and passes them to the output.
What you can do (if not already done): set the database connection encoding to UTF-8.

And double check, if this character is not already in the database ;)

(And yes, ÿ is of course an UTF-8 character ;) but it looks a little bit, that you are using a different encoding for the database connection, then what is store actually in the database)